# Python appending objects into a list- overwrite object issue

Tags: python

I struggled with the issue when appending objects into a list in Python. After retrieving JSON file, it assigns each value into **House** object and appends it into **houses** list. However, after appending the second object, it overwrites the first object in the list. Could you give me help?

**jsonfile.json**

```
 "features": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "id": "ea299c1e-2bbb-5a97-bb94-befe384f0eb2",
        "name": "Albert"
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "id": "47200ba4-db80-56fa-99ad-c4abe7296376",
        "name": "Batman"
    }
```

**python.py**

```
class House:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name=name


houses =[]

......

with open('./data/jsonfile.json', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    obj = json.loads(data)['features']
    for o in obj:
        print(o['properties']['id'])
        House.id = o['properties']['id']
        House.name = o['properties']['name]
        print(House.id)
        houses.append(House)
        print("----------------------")
    print("----------------------")
    print(houses[0].id)
    print(houses[1].id)
    print(len(houses))
```

**console**

```
ea299c1e-2bbb-5a97-bb94-befe384f0eb2
ea299c1e-2bbb-5a97-bb94-befe384f0eb2
----------------------
47200ba4-db80-56fa-99ad-c4abe7296376   
47200ba4-db80-56fa-99ad-c4abe7296376
----------------------
----------------------
47200ba4-db80-56fa-99ad-c4abe7296376. <--- It should be 'ea299c1e-2bbb-5a97-bb94-befe384f0eb2'
47200ba4-db80-56fa-99ad-c4abe7296376
2
```

Comment: You need to construct a new object for every house

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
House.id = o['properties']['id']
```

with

```
dahouse = House(o['properties']['id'])
```

then append `dahouse`.

The way you wrote it, you keep modifying the class not actually creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are not an instantiated object for house class. Please use the below code at that time append to the list.

```
houses.append(House(o['properties']['id']))
```